# My Random Walk program compiles but does not run

Tags: c

**Question:** Why was I able to compile my code successfully (without any warnings) but strangely enough it does not **run** and I have no idea as to the reason behind it. The problem I was solving was creating a random Walk using C and my code is mentioned below-

---

*This is the problem that I have been working on:*

> I am writing a C program randWalk.c that generates a random walk across a 10x10 array.
>
> Initially, the array will contain only dot characters (‘.’) and the start location in A[0][0].
>
> The program must randomly “walk” from element to element, always going up, down, left, or right by one step. The elements visited by the program will be labelled only with the letters A through Z, in the order visited (the walk stops after reaching the letter Z). When the walk is completed the program will print the final array values as shown in the example below:

[image]

> **Rules**
>   1. Before performing a move, check that:
>
> • It won’t go outside the array.
>
> • It doesn’t take the walk to an element that has already a letter assigned (blocked element).
>
> 2. If either condition is violated, try moving in another direction.
> 3. If all four directions are blocked, the program must terminate.

---

**MY Solution/Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ONE_DOT '.',
#define TWO_DOTS ONE_DOT ONE_DOT
#define FIVE_DOTS TWO_DOTS TWO_DOTS ONE_DOT
#define TEN_DOTS { FIVE_DOTS FIVE_DOTS },
#define TWENTY_DOTS TEN_DOTS TEN_DOTS
#define FIFTY_DOTS TWENTY_DOTS TWENTY_DOTS TEN_DOTS
#define ONE_HUNDRED_DOTS FIFTY_DOTS FIFTY_DOTS


int B[10][10] = {ONE_HUNDRED_DOTS};
char A[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 
              'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int a, b, c, d;
    int check;

    while (check != a + b + c + d)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand() % 4;

        switch (r)
        {
            case 0:
                i--;
                if (B[i][j] == '.')
                {
                    if (((0 <= i) && (i <= 10))&&((0 <= i) && (i <= 10)))
                    {
                        B[i][j] = A[n];
                        n++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    check = a + check;
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                j++;
                if (B[i][j] == '.')
                {
                    if (((0 <= i) && (i <= 10))&&((0 <= i) && (i <= 10)))
                    {
                        B[i][j] = A[n];
                        n++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    check = check + b;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                i++;
                if (B[i][j] == '.')
                {
                    if (((0 <= i) && (i <= 10))&&((0 <= i) && (i <= 10)))
                    {
                        B[i][j] = A[n];
                        n++;

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    check = check + c;
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                j--;
                if (B[i][j] == '.')
                {
                    if (((0 <= i) && (i <= 10))&&((0 <= i) && (i <= 10)))
                    {
                        B[i][j] = A[n];
                        n++;

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    check = check + d;
                }
                break;
        }

        int row, columns;
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for (int columns = 0; columns < 10; columns++)
            {
                printf("%d ", B[row][columns]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger? Does it get into main()? If it does, where does it block?

Comment: Why does one of your ...DOT `#define`s contain `{ braces }` but not the others?

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with the copyright notice, but user contributions to this site fall under a [creative commons license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: Too much white space... not enough indentation.

Comment: I'm just letting you know, so you understand what comes with posting here

Comment: *"it does not run"*. Does that mean the program does not run, or *does* run but fails, if so for what reason?

Comment: what do you mean by 'does not run'? What happens when you try to run it

Comment: @pm100  Its just an empty line and when you hit enter nothing happens

Comment: @LakshanRanathunga That means it's at least running. What's actually happening is that you either have an infinite loop or a very long loop

Comment: learn to use a debugger - gdb if you are on linux http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/

Comment: `srand` inside your loop is a recipe for sadness.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I don't see how this is going to work outside the loop. I need to generate a random value every time the loop runs.

Comment: You have omitted `...'H', 'I', ...` from the initialisation of `char A[26]`

Comment: @LakshanRanathunga please read the man pages about `srand` and `rand`. `srand` seeds the sequence of `rand`. You do it *once* at the start of your program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing what I noticed is

```
int a,b,c,d;
int check;

while(check!=a+b+c+d)
```

Using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior so your code is not working

Comment: Consider using a do{}while(); instead, though a, b, c, d and check don't seem to be initialized anywhere else anyway

Comment: @KABoissonneault Can you explain please

Comment: I'm just saying, if you don't want to initialize a, b, c, d and check before the loop, then you shouldn't evaluate the condition at the start of the loop, it should evaluate after the loop.
But it also seems that you don't give any of those variables a proper value, therefore it won't change the undefined behavior of your program

Answer (score -1):

The variables check, a, b, c, d are all unitialized leading to the comparison of garbage values. The while loop might never even be executed.

Comment: As already answered by @Gopi 20 minutes ago.